# NuGet fails to install Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core - 'Failed to generate binding redirects'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, visual-studio-2012

Trying to install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core' 1.0 with NuGet 2.0.30619.9119 in Visual Studio 2012 RC/.NET 4.0/MVC 4, I get this error message from NuGet:

```
Failed to generate binding redirects for 'MyProject'. Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

What does this mean? Is there some way to work around it? I've got a corresponding [bug report](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2488) at CodePlex for this package.

Comment: did you get it towork somehow ?

Comment: @ashutoshraina I tried again today, and it works now. Not sure if the issue has been fixed or if it was intermittent on my end.

Comment: nope mine still gives the same error.. Could be admin priveleges issue...

Comment: @ashutoshraina I'm out of ideas really. I think your best option would be to chime in at http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2488.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be solved with version 1.1 of Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core and version 2.1.31002.9028 of NuGet.